# HTTPS request “Secure” & “HTTP” attribute (column checked in browser) in Authenticated Session Cookies: Django, GAE, Python

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, session, cookies

I'm bit newbie for secure authenticated session cookies related stuff.

Here is example app url having `https` : `https://app_name.app.appspot.com`

Am just authenticating user using,

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def authenticate_user(request):
   user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
   if user:
      login(request, user)
      request.session.set_expiry(14*60*60) #setting up expiration for 24 hours
      return HttpResponseRedirect('app/home')
 def home(request):
    #Other Stuff
 return render_to_response(request, 'myapp/home.html', locals())
```

Here in this browser resources Name column showing default **sessionid** but `HTTP` column & `Secure` column is not checked.

[image]

**EDIT:** I'm using django's version: **"1.2"** in app.yaml

Can any body please help me over `HTTP` & `Secure` attribute?

And even I'm not able to see `SACSID` or `ACSID` cookie, Anybody have solution or trick of it?, Please suggest me how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [`SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE) and [`SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY) flags in your settings:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

Comment: @Martijin: Thanks for your reply, Emm..That is the only thing need to do for `secure` and `HTTP` attribute?

Comment: @Niks: for session cookies this is what it takes.

Comment: @Martijin: I just add these two flag in my `settings.py`. But it is same as i posted a snap above.
Please suggest me where am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Niks: it's impossible for me to tell what else might be wrong here.

Comment: @Martijin: Actually i'm using django version: "1.2" for Google App Engine. Is that the issue?

Comment: @Niks: that is an ancient version. Yes, that could very well be an issue. Use a newer version, 1.2 is no longer supported. Looking at the GitHub source `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` is not supported in 1.2.

Comment: @Niks: HTTPOnly support for session cookies was only added in [this commit, part of Django 1.3](https://github.com/django/django/commit/78be884ea788835ad98ad433862a82cf192c3d4f#diff-7e0a8bc945a2cf57bf4e4b4c9804c340). Note the date, that's almost 4 years ago.

Comment: The `Path` is `/`. Can we change it '/our_app_name'?

Comment: @shaikmoeed: yes, if you want the cookie to only be sent to URLs whose path start with that string.

Answer (score -1):

Hushh...

Finally I got my answer after trying so many things,

Initially i was using Django - v1.2. i replaced that with v1.4

Then in `settings.py` I set 3 flags,

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/;HttpOnly'
```

Using, These 3 flags session cookies become `secure` & `HTTP only` as well.

Special thanks to @Martijn Pieters :)

Comment: Setting the cookie path to add `/;HttpOnly` won't work as the path is quoted. Instead your browser will not send back the cookie to the server unless the path starts with `/;HttpOnly`.